# Key security fixes - pace of adoption into 12.04 LTS

Tags: security, lts

I would like to ask about how quickly security issues are dealt with in the 12.04 disti.  I am recently using GnuPG on my 12.04 box and am concerned that the following security fix / most up to date version of GPG is not available yet for ubuntu.

Can someone with more knowledge comment on that (http://www.debian.org/security/2013/dsa-2821) and more generally regarding how quickly security patches/updates get flowed into the ubuntu package (http://www.debian.org/security/).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted refers to:

> Security database references:
>
> In Mitre's CVE dictionary: CVE-2013-4576.

From [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnupg) and the changelog for the security updates for 12.04:

> **Publishing details**
>
> Published on 2013-12-18. Copied from ubuntu precise in Private PPA for Ubuntu Security Team by Ubuntu Archive Robot
>
> **Changelog**
>
> gnupg (1.4.11-3ubuntu2.5) precise-security; urgency=low
>
> - SECURITY UPDATE: RSA Key Extraction via Low-Bandwidth Acoustic
>     Cryptanalysis attack
>
>   - **debian/patches/CVE-2013-4576.dpatch**: Use blinding for the RSA secret
>       operation in cipher/random.*, cipher/rsa.c, g10/gpgv.c. Normalize the
>       MPIs used as input to secret key functions in cipher/dsa.c,
>       cipher/elgamal.c, cipher/rsa.c.
>   - CVE-2013-4576  -- Marc Deslauriers    Wed, 18 Dec 2013 11:17:02 -0500

---

So I would assume you should have (or at least are able to get) this update as of 18.12.2013. And regarding the speed of updates: in this case it was updated the same day.

Comment: Much appreciated! however, when I check the gpg --version against the gnupg website reflecting the version that has this fixed, my ubuntu is showing an older version (1.4.11) leading me to believe that mine is out of date. Any good ideas here - I have run apt-get update etc to keep the box up to date. Thank you!

Comment: You can find the DEB here: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ppa/+build/5362742 (64) and here https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ppa/+build/5362745 (32)

Comment: Much appreciated. The implication is that there is no problem that my GPG reads as version 1.4.11 even though the Gnu website says the stable release is 1.4.15 with that update. This nomenclature was confusing but it certainly appears that I would have received the patch as did all other users.